# How to return multiple varchar from a stored procedure where condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I have created a Table in which I am storing first name, last name and email ID of some persons.

The table is as follows:

```
create table frnds
(
id int Primary Key,
firstName varchar (20) not null,
lastName varchar (20) not null,
emailID varchar (30)not null
)
```

I have to write a Stored Procedure to return the "first name" values from the table wherever there is a match with the input "last name" value. 
I have some of the names with common last names. So I want to have all the first names as the output of the Stored Procedure.

I am using the following code to do that but have been able to get only one matching first name as output.

```
Create Procedure GetFirstName
(
@lastName varchar(20),
@firstName varchar(20) OUT
)
AS 
Begin
Select @firstName = firstName from frnds where lastName = @lastName
End
```

Also this is how I am displaying the result:

```
declare @LastName varchar (20)
Exec GetFirstName Daniels, @LastName output 
select @LastName
```

I know that this is because I have the output parameter such that it can hold only one matching first name. Since I am new to SQL, I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. Please help with any suggestion or some link which can guide me in the right direction.
Thanks!!!

Comment: I see two people have answered with similar solutions, so I'm sure I'm just totally missing something, but is there a reason a good old-fashioned `SELECT` won't do it? `SELECT firstName FROM frnds WHERE lastName = @lastName`?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I checked it and the "good old-fashioned" SELECT works just fine. So simple...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary table do store the varchars.

First create your procedure like this:

```
Create table #temp
(
  fisrtName varchar(20) not null
)
go
Create Procedure GetFirstName
(
@lastName varchar(20)
-- , @firstName varchar(20) OUT with my solution you don't need it
)
AS 
Begin
insert into  #temp
Select firstName from frnds where lastName = @lastName
End
go
drop table #temp
```

Then you can use it as below

```
Create table #temp
(
  fisrtName varchar(20) not null
)
exec  GetFirstName 'Daniels'
select * from #temp
```

Comment: Great this works...But can you please elaborate the need to drop the table and again create it?

Comment: First create/drop is only for build in procedure. Second create you have to do every time when you want to call GetFirstName procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Create Procedure GetFirstName
(
@lastName varchar(20),
@firstName varchar(20) OUT
)
AS 
Begin
Select  firstName from frnds where lastName = @lastName
End

Create table #lastname(lastname varchar (20))
Insert into #lastname
Exec GetFirstName 'Daniels'
select * from #lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [myschema].[returnLastNames]
(
    @lastName varchar(20),
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN SELECT firstName from frnds where lastName = @lastName;
```

A function might be better here maybe?

Use it like f.ex.:

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.returnLastNames('Stevensson');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('usp_GetFirstName', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_GetFirstName;
GO

Create Procedure usp_GetFirstName
(
@lastName varchar(20),
@firstName varchar(20) OUTPUT
)
AS 
Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select @firstName = firstName from frnds where lastName = @lastName;
RETURN
End
GO 

DECLARE @Person varchar(20);

EXECUTE usp_GetFirstName
N'Daniels',@lastName = @Person OUTPUT;
PRINT 'LAST NAme IS' + @Person;
GO
```